# Are there more professional programmable (Android, etc.) cameras than the Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I need a programmable camera device. I want take products photo for e-commerce with the fastly website. I bought a [Samsung Galaxy (3G)](http://www.samsung.com/tr/c/p/EK-GC100ZKATUR) camera. I developed a small android app. My app sends captured photos to a server. After upload, photos auto-actioning with Photoshop (this is different web application).

I want a more professional programmable camera. What do you recommend? The camera can be android or other simple OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canon has a [software development kit for EOS cameras](https://www.didp.canon-europa.com), and the community-built [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) gives you control over many non-EOS models. [Nikon also has an SDK](https://sdk.nikonimaging.com/apply/) that may help. Olympus has its own [SDK](http://www.olympusamerica.com/cpg_section/cpg_pressDetails.asp?pressNo=105) too, though it seems to require payment for commercial purposes. And [Sony has an SDK](https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/) that supports several camera styles.

Digital cameras are basically powerful computers connected to image sensors, so if you have a camera in mind, check to see if the manufacturer offers an SDK. You may have to be a bit flexible in your choice of platform -- you might have to use Mac or Windows instead of Android, but the basic goal of capturing an image and sending it to a server is certainly possible.

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need a programmable camera for this use case. You can shoot tethered with a camera attached to a computer/notebook/tablet via USB or wireless, or upload photos to a computer from a wifi enabled camera, or a camera with a wifi sd card.

I don't know whether wifi enabled cameras can auto-upload each shot, but if not you'd just need software on the PC side to continually pull the pictures from the camera.

Answer (score 2):

If, by "professional", you mean a large-sensored camera with an interchangeable lens mount, there is no choice. The [Samsung Galaxy NX](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxycamera/nx/) is the only one available.  Smart cameras aren't really a market sector, and as you may have noted, Samsung seems to be the only real proponent.